# How to add add SSL .cert to chopper client?

Tags: flutter, dart, ssl, chopper

In flutter I try to create with chopper a request to a backend url.

To my `ChopperClient` I try to provide a TLS certificate. I have the certificate
as a file tls.cert

How do I add this to my chopper requests?